# useSelector with argument causes Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, redux

I currently have this selector:

```
export const getTasksForProjectSelector = (state, projectSlug) => state.task.tasks.filter((task) => task.project.slug === projectSlug);
```

which should filter for tasks that belong to a certain project. I'm calling the selector with

```
  const tasks = useSelector((state) => getTasksForProjectSelector(state, projectSlug));
```

but this causes a `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded` error. I've also tried to rewrite the selector like:

```
export const getTasksForProjectSelector = (projectSlug) => (state) => state.task.tasks.filter((task) => task.project.slug === projectSlug);
```

but the same error appears.
I'm sure that the error is becase of the selector because when I call an ordinary selector (without passing an argument) to get all tasks such as `(state) => state.task.tasks`, everything works as it should

Answer (score 2):

Your selector creates a new array on every invocation, so `lastValue !== newValue` will always be true and always cause a rerender.

For something like this, you need to use a memoized selector, e.g. with reselect:

```
export const getTasksForProjectSelector = createSelector(
  state => state.task.tasks
  (state, projectSlug) => projectSlug,
  (tasks, projectSlug) => 
    tasks.filter((task) => task.project.slug === projectSlug)
)
```

I'd recommend reading up the Redux docs on [derived data](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data)